# Probability of picking 3 males with similar names before 6 females with similar name in class contain 36 student

Tags: probability

We have a class of 36 students, 3 of the students called john and 6 called Marie, what is the Probability of picking student called john before student called Marie?

Comment: Are they picked with replacement?  And does it matter?

Comment: no that doesn't matter
You just pick, and the only important thing that john picked before marie

Answer (score 1):

There are only 9 people in the class who decide the question:  the three Johns and the 6 Maries.  The other 27 just delay the decision.

So the chance of picking a John first is $\frac{3}{9}=\frac{1}{3}$